# Trying to access and delete from list of lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm trying to access to a position of a list of lists, take the value and delete from another list.

For example, I have a list with this data (l1):

```
(((a1) (a2) (a3)) ((a4) (a5) (a6)))
```

And another list (l2) with:

```
 ((a1) (a2) (a3) (a4) (a5) (a6))
```

Now, I want to delete a1, a2 and a3 from the second list using the firstlist, ie. I want to access to a1 a2 and a3 from the first list and delete it from second list, but, when I try to do it, the result list is the same that the second one.

My code is:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (delete-from-list l1 l2)
  (let ((laux '()))
       (for/list ([e (in-list l1)])
         (for/list ([i (length e)])
           (set! laux (delete (list-ref e i) l2))
         )
        )
     (values laux)
   )
)
```

And the result with the examples list is:

```
((a1) (a2) (a3) (a4) (a5) (a6))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `delete` in `(set! laux (delete ...`? I get the following error: `delete: unbound identifier in module in: delete`.

Comment: @uselpa It's a function of srfi/1 library. I've added the line to the question.

Comment: Your `l1` list is a list of lists as 3 sublists followed by 3 sublists.  Is this sublist structure important or just coincidental?  Can their be arbitrary elements in the list (like more than 3)?  Can their be more than two sublists? The structure of `l2` is always a list of 1 element lists?

Comment: @GoZoner The structure is important, I think. Not always you have the same number of sublists. You can have, for example, `(((a1) (a2)) ((a3) (a4)) ((a5) (a6)))`,ie. more than two sublists can be found. And yes. The structure of `l2` is always the same. Although the question is answered, thx a lot for these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this

```
#lang racket

(define l1 '(((a1) (a2) (a3)) ((a4) (a5) (a6))))

(define l2 '((a1) (a2) (a3) (a4) (a5) (a6)))

;; a new list without the elements in the first of l1:

(remove* (first l1) l2)
```

... which evaluates to `'((a4) (a5) (a6))`.

As a side comment, I'm secretly steering you away from mutation.

Also, it's a little strange to me that all of your items are nested lists.

Finally, I have a completely different (set of) answer(s) for you if this is for a class.

Comment: It's what I needed. I'm going to adapt it to a more difficult problem (more than 2 sublists). Thx a lot for the answer = )